# References for "Multidimensional Sturm-Liouville Theory"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am interested in what I'll call (perhaps erroneously) *multivariate Sturm–Liouville theory*, i.e., solutions to equations of the form
$$\nabla\cdot(P(x)\nabla Y)+Q(x)Y=-\lambda W(x)Y\tag{1}$$
for $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, $Y:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$, and $P,Q,W:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$.

If $d=1$, then, as shown on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) page, there is a very well developed theory for solutions of $(1)$ on an interval $[a,b]$ with fixed boundary conditions. This is called Sturm-Liouville theory.

I suspect that such a theory has been generalized to higher dimensions. However, after googling for a while using keywords such as "multivariate Sturm-Liouville theory", I'm starting to suspect that the study of $(1)$ in higher dimensions has a different name, since I've completely failed to find good comprehensive resources on such problems.

> **Question:** Are there textbooks that treat multivariate problems such as $(1)$ in detail? I'm especially interested in fixed point-type arguments for existence and uniqueness, as well as continuity results for the solution $(Y,\lambda)$ with respect to the "data" $P,Q,W$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming $P$ has constant sign, this is a well-studied class of problems, with the usual terminology being something like "weighted elliptic eigenvalue problem".

In the case $W=1,$ you have the standard eigenvalue problem for the divergence-form linear elliptic operator $L=\operatorname{div} P\, \nabla + Q,$ which is usually analyzed using Fredholm theory - see, for example, the end of Chapter 8 of *Elliptic PDE of Second Order* by Gilbarg and Trudinger. There has been a huge amount written about elliptic eigenvalue problems which you should have no problems finding online.

When you add the weight $W,$ you're in to marginally less standard territory; but there's still a lot out there. If $W>0$ then I'm guessing you can say quite a bit by rewriting the problem as a standard eigenvalue problem for the unknown $U = WY.$ In more generality, it seems there have been [many articles](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=elliptic+eigenvalue+indefinite+weight) written on the topic of elliptic eigenvalue problems with an indefinite weight function.

Answer (score 1):

Haberman briefly discusses this in *Applied Partial Differential Equations with Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems (Classic Version)*, 2018, section 7.4. However, he lets $P = W = 1$ and $Q = 0$ before establishing theorems. He calls this the **Helmholtz equation** and calls the problem (with certain boundary conditions) a "multidimensional eigenvalue problem." Furthermore, he says it is "directly analogous to the one-dimensional regular Sturm–Liouville eigenvalue problem."